# Animating element height by "blinking" to auto to get final value

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to animate an element's height from a preset one to the one that's dependent on what's inside (what `height: auto` would set). Because an animation doesn't work for `height: auto` (going to or from) I thought a solution could be to save the current height, set `height: auto` on an element to get the final height and save that, then reset the element's height to initial and then set it to the final height. The "blink to auto" the user wouldn't notice and the last change should result in an animation.

```js
const containerBlockDiv = document.querySelector('.container-block')
const childBlockDiv = document.querySelector('.child-block')

const containerCurrentHeight = containerBlockDiv.scrollHeight
containerBlockDiv.style.height = 'auto'
const containerNewHeight = containerBlockDiv.scrollHeight
containerBlockDiv.style.height = `${containerCurrentHeight}px`
containerBlockDiv.style.height = `${containerNewHeight}px`
```

```css
.container-block {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 20px;
  transition: height 1s;
}

.child-block {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-block">
  <div class="child-block"></div>
</div>
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: I'm pretty sure transitions don't work on styles set via Javascript, first of all. I would use JS to add a class and set the styles you want for that class using CSS.

Comment: Use `max-height` for animation here, not `height` and then you can set the `height:auto` with no issue.

Comment: They do https://codepen.io/warhammered_cat/pen/yLVPXRV. @kdsprogrammer

Comment: @StefanBajić cool, learned something new today

Comment: All the CSSOM ever sees here is the last `containerBlockDiv.style.height = \`${containerNewHeight}px\``. You need to force it to parse the intermediate value, by forcing what's called a reflow between the two value settings. https://jsfiddle.net/2anv6gru/

Comment: If it only sees the last value, why doesn't it animate between the first value and the last? @Kaiido

Comment: Because it doesn't even see the first value. It can't transition from nothing.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't see the first value? The height is defined to be 50px in .container-block? If it sees that and sees the last one containerBlockDiv.style.height = `${containerNewHeight}px` it should be able to animate between them? @Kaiido

Comment: I mean it doesn't even see the 50px value either. Your script runs before the first reflow. Read the accepted answer in the linked question and all the linked answers from there, I've written enough about this I think.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help me out. @Kaiido

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have in my spellbook to animate a div from 0 (or any other fixed value) to `auto` : pure CSS, no JS

```css
div {
  max-height: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: red dashed 1px;
  transition: max-height 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
}

div:hover {
  max-height: 9999px;
  transition: max-height 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 0);
}
```

```html
<div>Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some
  content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content
  Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content</div>
```

Comment: I don't like this approach, because to quote CSS tricks: "The transition length will not actually be what you specify unless the content height works out to be exactly the same as max-height". Anyway, I asked why what I tried doesn't work, not for an alternative approach.